# error of using purecomputed function of knockoutjs in devextreme

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2012, knockout.js

This is my dxview:-
I am using knockoutjs in the visual studio.

```
<div data-options="dxView : { name: 'home', title: 'Home' } " >
    <div class="home-view"  data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } " >
        <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
        <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
        <h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript in visual studio using devextreme:-

```
MyFirstProject.home = function (params)
 {

   var viewModel = function (first, last) {
        this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
        this.lastName = ko.observable(last);
        this.fullName = ko.PureComputed(function ()
        {
            return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();

        },this);
   };
   ko.applyBindings(new viewModel("Planet", "Earth"));
    return viewModel;
};
```

This give an while i am running this program.
The error is on pureComputed function of knockoutjs.
I am not able to understand why there is an error like:-
Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function', line 6, file 'http://localhost:51146/views/home.js'.

please tell me about this.
Thank you.

Comment: which version of ko you are using @dev ?

Comment: I am using knockout-3.1.0.js

Comment: pure computed is introduced in ko 3.2.0 so it will be undefined in 3.1.0 . try using 3.2.0 . cheers

Comment: Ok , then what function in the 3.1.0 which i can use in the place of pureComputed

Comment: simple use `ko.computed` . cheers

Comment: thats a different issue the error states that you are using `ko.applybindings` multiple times on same viewmodel . check it

Comment: i have used it already but it give an error. Its give an error like:-Error: 'Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.', line 58, file 'localhost:51146/js/knockout-3.1.0.js';.

Comment: devextreme calls applybindings for you. You can remove the applyBindings call from your code.

Comment: I am not understand why there is an error

Comment: Ohk Matt Jacobsen, then how i send the parameter to the viewModel.if i am not using the ko.applybindings(new viewModel("Planet", "Earth"));

Comment: i hope you are looking at this example which works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU/ . if you are calling `MyFirstProject.home` there is a chance of `ko.applybindings` inside to it calling again .

Comment: Yes it is working on jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU.Can you please tell me how?

Comment: simple . Here viewmodel is not inside a function as far your code goes your VM is inside a function and i belive you are calling the function somewhere multiple times which making to pop up `cannot apply bindings multiple times` .

Comment: ohk,what i can do,so that multiple binding not perform

Comment: well you can use `cleanNode` (not advisable at first place) try figure out a better work around . using cleanNode Check herehttp://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/23470/ . cheers

Comment: ko.applyBindings(new viewModel("Planet", "Earth"),
    document.getElementById('liveExample'));
    setTimeout(function () {
        ko.cleanNode($('#liveExample')[0]);
    });                                                                                                                                                                                                 I am do this but this still give an error like:- Error: 'Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.', line 58, file 'http://localhost:51146/js/knockout-3.1.0.js'.

Comment: @dev you should not use my code copy/paste you should use it according to your requirement  .

Answer (score 0):

You might have applied bindings in the view multiple times. You should probably bind the viewmodel to a specific element. Try doing this.

Define id attribute to the div. Example:

```
 <div id="one" data-options="dxView : { name: 'home', title: 'Home' } " >
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("one"));
```

Comment: I try this but this give an error.                                                               Error: 'Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.', line 58, file 'http://localhost:51146/js/knockout-3.1.0.js'.

Comment: This error occurs only when you applyBinding to same element multiple times. See if the parent of this "div" has already a binding. If so, then are you are trying to define a different binding to the "div" within a parent "div" which has already a binding. In such case you should use the [With binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html)

Comment: I meant the complete code :). In Jsfiddle see console. It says "MyFirstProject is not defined". Can you please update your code in Jsfiddle so that it has complete html and scripts. Especially the complete html

Comment: [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/wveqamd5/2/)  See console. You must be getting this error.  Now, [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/wveqamd5/1/). you have to specify the id if you want to have multiple bindings

Comment: see the updated links. when you try to applyBinding to id "one" the second time it throws error.

Comment: I got my mistake.In devextreme it automatically perform binding.                 i am writing :-                                                                                        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel("Planet", "Earth"));
    return viewModel;                                                                                   I have to write :-  return viewModel("Planet", "Earth");                                  Thank you everyone for help me and thank you Aathreya